# Return distinct last logon date from the following table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a query in MSSQL to return the following result:

Client ID, UserName, EventDate

distinctly for each ClientID based on the most recent date from the following table :

[image: Login History table]

e.g : Given the table above, return :

```
  450SB 2013-03-01 16:40:29 nevadan
  LASB  2013-03 001 16:37:27 siteuser
```

etc

Was thinking of creating a cursor for a : SELECT DISTINCT ClientId from TABLE
and looping through each returning only entry of maxdate, but didn't think it
was very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE to grab the latest access dates for each client, then JOIN back on the CTE to get the username for each of the latest access dates for each client. The JOIN would be better in terms of performance, readability, and elegance if your table had a primary key though.

```
;WITH   latestClientAccess (ClientId, LatestEventDate) AS (
        SELECT  ClientId, MAX(EventDate)
        FROM    MyTable
        GROUP   BY ClientId
)
SELECT  t.ClientId, t.UserName, lca.LatestEventDate [EventDate]
FROM    MyTable t
INNER   JOIN latestClientAccess lca
        ON  t.ClientId=lca.ClientId
            AND  t.EventDate=lca.LatestEventDate
```

A quick local test for the concept and script above can be performed by running the script below. This way, anyone else looking at this response can test without having to create any schema.

```
declare @temp table(ClientId int, EventDate datetime, UserName varchar(20)) 

insert  into @temp
select  1, '2015-11-06 00:00:00', 'user1'

insert  into @temp
select  2, '2015-11-06 00:01:00', 'user1'

insert  into @temp
select  1, '2015-11-06 00:01:00', 'user2'

insert  into @temp
select  1, '2015-11-06 00:03:00', 'user1'

;WITH   latestClientAccess (ClientId, LatestEventDate) AS (
        SELECT  ClientId, MAX(EventDate)
        FROM    @temp
        GROUP   BY ClientId
)
SELECT  t.ClientId, t.UserName, lca.LatestEventDate [EventDate]
FROM    @temp t
INNER   JOIN latestClientAccess lca
        ON  t.ClientId=lca.ClientId
            AND  t.EventDate=lca.LatestEventDate
```

**EDIT**

Considering you do have a primary key and a second table with the client name, consider the scripts below:

```
;WITH   latestClientAccess (ClientId, HistoryId) AS (
        SELECT  ClientId, MAX(HistoryId)
        FROM    MyTable
        GROUP   BY ClientId
)
SELECT  ct.ClientName, t.UserName, t.EventDate
FROM    MyTable t
INNER   JOIN latestClientAccess lca
        ON  t.HistoryId=lca.HistoryId
INNER   JOIN MyClientTable ct
        ON  t.ClientId=ct.ClientId
```

For quick test of latest event concept (without client name):

```
declare @temp table(HistoryId int, ClientId int, EventDate datetime, UserName varchar(20)) 

insert  into @temp
select  1, 1, '2015-11-06 00:00:00', 'user1'

insert  into @temp
select  2, 2, '2015-11-06 00:01:00', 'user1'

insert  into @temp
select  3, 1, '2015-11-06 00:01:00', 'user2'

insert  into @temp
select  4, 1, '2015-11-06 00:03:00', 'user1'

;WITH   latestClientAccess (ClientId, HistoryId) AS (
        SELECT  ClientId, MAX(HistoryId)
        FROM    @temp
        GROUP   BY ClientId
)
SELECT  t.ClientId, t.UserName, t.EventDate
FROM    @temp t
INNER   JOIN latestClientAccess lca
        ON  t.HistoryId=lca.HistoryId
```

Comment: It does hava a primary : History ID -Thank you.

Comment: If HistoryID is an ever-increasing identity field you could use MAX(HistoryID) instead of MAX(EventDate). This may speed up the join a little bit.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. If I wanted to return in the query a more explicit name for clientId which resides in tableB as field sccCompanyName on tableb.sccClientID = table.clientId. How would I modify your query?

Comment: @IanFalcon - I have updated my response with an example for your primary key and client name table. On SO, please included as much of your question as possible in the original question. This would have allowed me to provide a solution without so many subsequent edits. That said, if this meets your needs, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I apologize bitxwise. First timer, will improve on my future questions. Could you please help with the join to the tableB to close the question?. Thank you much, sir

Comment: @IanFalcon - The 3rd query in my response addresses your tableB. I simply called it MyClientTable instead of tableB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MSSQL installed on my computer so I can't test this for you but alternatively I think you can add the "ORDERBY ASC eventdate" filter to your SQL and then only select the first row to achieve your goal.

So it will be something like

SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
  FROM TABLE
 ORDER BY eventdate

As to whether this is more efficient or not... I think you willl have to look at the query execution plan to see what operations are done by the MSSQL to do the query, performance wise probably not as good as your previous one because this SQL is doing something extra, that is sorting.

With this approach at least you don't have to think of efficient sort algorithm yourself and it saves you time thinking of the algorithm and couple lines of code :P

Comment: Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Ooops, I dont have much experience with MSSQL but you can try using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT? so something like this;

Select ClientID, UserName, EventDate From Table Group By ClientId Order by eventdate asc

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a little more complicated than one would think, mostly because you need UserName in addition to ClientID and EventDate.

This should work, although I didn't build your schema up locally to test, so let me know if you get any errors.

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    SomeTable t1
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        ClientId
        MaxEventDate = MAX(EventDate)
    FROM
        SomeTable
    GROUP BY
        ClientId
    ) t2
ON
    t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID
    AND t1.EventDate = t2.EventDate
```

...note: if you get rid of UserName it's just:

```
SELECT
    ClientId
    MaxEventDate = MAX(EventDate)
FROM
    SomeTable
GROUP BY
    ClientId
```